# updating data from source DB1 table to anaother destination DB2 table not working

Tags: mysql, database

i have 2 databases namely `DB1`  and `DB2`. Both Databases has one table named `MyTable`
While `MyTable` in `DB1` has outdated values and `MyTable` in `DB2` has new values. I wanted to update `MyTable` in `DB1` with `MyTable` of `DB2`.

MySql version `5.1.61-0ubuntu0.11.10.1 (Ubuntu)`

i tried like this(from within DB1)

```
update MyTable a, DB2.MyTable b set a.name=b.name where a.id=b.id;
```

But this is leading to

```
ERROR 1206 (HY000): The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size
```

as referred to error i increased buffer size to 64MB `innodb_buffer_pool_size=64MB` in `my.conf`  file and restarted mysql service but still the same error showing.

Can anyone suggest me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Are all values in DB1.MyTable outdated or just one column (i.e. you want to copy the entire DB2.MyTable into the other or just update a column)?

Comment: @MarcellFülöp only one column data is outdated(name)

Comment: @h.APP.y The question you link to in your question is for a completely different database system. That question targets Microsoft SQL Server 2005 whilst by the looks of it you are using MySQL.

Comment: @AeroX Thanks for the observation. In searching for solution to my question i forget the tag below the answer what i referred. Posting the answer for my problem in answer section.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE DB1.dbo.MyTable AS dest JOIN DB2.dbo.MyTable AS src ON dest.id=src.id
    SET dest.name=src.name;
```

Comment: when i try your query outside databases it throws me `No database selected` and when tried inside `dest` database it gives me `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from DB1.MyTable as dest join annadaata_for_report.session_' at line 1`

Comment: Please avoid posting code samples only. The best answers explain the why and how along with the solution so that everyone here now and in the future can learn more.

Comment: @Rafiq I apologies. My question was related to MySql and i referred a Microsoft Sql Server answer, that was the problem.Sorry for your valuable  time posting the solution what i got in answer.

Answer (score 0):

As noticed by AeroX i was referred a different tag for my question.

The problem arised due to my MySql version (which is 5.1.x) and db engine.

Finally i found solution to my problem from referencing [here](http://mrothouse.wordpress.com/2006/10/20/mysql-error-1206/) and [here](https://major.io/2010/02/16/mysql-the-total-number-of-locks-exceeds-the-lock-table-size-2/).

as they suggested it could be solved by

1. Adjust innodb_buffer_pool_size and restart MySQL.

   ```
              or
   ```
2. Reduce the amount of rows you’re manipulating in one query.

And the reason for this error is 
***“The SQL statement sets locks on all the records it scans. If you have a small buffer pool, then the InnoDB lock table may indeed grow so big that it does not fit in the buffer pool. “***

The same query runs in MySQL version 5.6.x perfectly.